# why 3==new Number(3) gives true why?

Tags: javascript

I follow the below links

[Why should you not use Number as a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor)
[Question about object.method in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369424/question-about-object-method-in-javascript)

why 3==new Number(3) gives true why ??

`3== new Number(3)` // `true`

As of I know `==` only check the value.but new Number(3) is a object how it value become `3`.

how `new Number(3)` value is `3`

Comment: What does `new Number(3).valueOf()` return?

Comment: why this question got - , while the answer have 3 valid rates + more than one answer, which mean it was helpful question and people wanted it (-1) must be reasoned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), or `x == y`, does, on step 10:

> If Type(x) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

So the evaluation of

```
3 == new Number(3)
```

becomes

```
3 == Number(new Number(3))
```

Although `new Number(3)` results in a (number) object, it then gets cast to its primitive value (a plain non-object number), and `3 == 3` is `true`.

Comment: Also if you want to compare without coercing the values, you should use `===`

Answer (score 2):

It's giving true because of [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) in javascript.

Javascript will convert object to number implicitly while evaluating equality operation.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that `==` coerces the data type for comparison to be done, your basic question of:

> As of I know `==` only check the value.but `new Number(3)` is a object how
> it value become `3`.

has a different answer. All objects in JavaScript inherit from `Object.prototype` and that object has a [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and a [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. These methods are automatically used by the JavaScript runtime when the fundamental (primitive) value or string representation of that value are required. So in this case, although `new Number(3)` returns an object, the `valueOf()` method is implicitly being called to return the value of `3` for the rest of the expression to work with.

From the MDN link above:

> JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a
> primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf` method
> yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an
> object where a primitive value is expected.

These methods are automatically called when needed, as I said, but you can call them as well on any object:

```js
// There will be no implicit call for .valueOf here because there is no 
// context for the JS runtime to know what you want to do with the object.
// Instead, you get {}, which means Object
console.log(new Number(3));  // {} 

// But, you can get the most basic value if you want:
console.log(new Number(3).valueOf());  // 3
```