# How to escape and unescape quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Here's a short piece of code:

```
var utility = {
    escapeQuotes: function(string) {
        return string.replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'),'\\"');
    },
    unescapeQuotes: function(string) {
        return string.replace(new RegExp('\\"', 'g'),'"');
    }
};

var a = 'hi "';

var b = utility.escapeQuotes(a);
var c = utility.unescapeQuotes(b);

console.log(b + ' | ' + c);
```

I would expect this code to work, however as a result I receive:

```
hi \" | hi \"
```

If I change the first parameter of the new RegExp constructor in the unescapeQuotes method to 4 backslashes everything starts working as it should.

```
string.replace(new RegExp('\\\\"', 'g'),'"');
```

The result:

```
hi \" | hi "
```

**Why are four backslashes needed as the first parameter of the new RegExp constructor? Why doesn't it work with only 2 of them?**

Comment: [Primitive constructors shouldn't be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395572/literal-vs-constructor-notation-for-primitives-which-is-more-proper-for-starter/21395747#21395747) in most cases, including your case. Instead of `new RegExp('\\"', 'g')`, you should do `/\\"/g` to avoid unexpected weird string interpretations by the constructor (and incorrect returned values).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `RegExp` constructor, which accepts a string, rather than using a regular expression literal. So in this line in your unescape:

```
return string.replace(new RegExp('\\"', 'g'),'"');
```

...the `\\` is interpreted by the JavaScript parser as part handling the *string*, resulting in a *single* backslash being handed to the regular expression parser. So the expression the regular expression parser sees is `\"`. The backslash is an escape character in regex, too, but `\"` doesn't mean anything special and just ends up being `"`. To have an actual backslash in a regex, you have to have two of them; to do that in a string literal, you have to have *four* (so they survive both layers of interpretation).

Unless you have a very good reason to use the `RegExp` constructor (e.g., you have to use some varying input), always use the literal form:

```
var utility = {
    escapeQuotes: function(string) {
        return string.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
    },
    unescapeQuotes: function(string) {
        return string.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
    }
};
```

It's a lot less confusing.