# Get data from JSON array within JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to get data from a JSON array within a JSON array, but am having little success.

So our server returns a JSON array within a variable called 'msg', which look like this when I console.log it

```
[{"product":"[{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332401\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 1",\"productCode\":\"332401\"},{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332388\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 2",\"productCode\":\"332388\"}]","category":"gross_MAX_1","totalCategory":1},{"product":"[{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332401\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 1",\"productCode\":\"332401\"},{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332388\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 2",\"productCode\":\"332388\"}]","category":"gross_MAX_1","totalCategory":1}]
```

I then have the following code to pull out the product name but keep getting an undefined error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prodName' of undefined

```
console.log(msg);
var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
console.log(data);

OBJ = {};
OBJ.apply = function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(this, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value.product.prodName);
        });
    });
};
OBJ.apply(data);
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

EDIT

I've looked at the parsed variable and I get:-

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
category: "restrictedItems_ie-standard-gross_MAX_1"
product: "[{"imgUrl":"/p/332401","prodCartQty":2,"prodName":"Test Product 1","productCode":"332401"},{"imgUrl":"/p/332388","prodCartQty":2,"prodName":"Test Product 2","productCode":"332388"}]"
totalCategory: 1
__proto__: Object
1: Object
category: "restrictedItems_ie-standard-gross_MAX_1"
product: "[{"imgUrl":"/p/332401","prodCartQty":2,"prodName":"Test Product 1","productCode":"332401"},{"imgUrl":"/p/332388","prodCartQty":2,"prodName":"Test Product 2","productCode":"332388"}]"
totalCategory: 1
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

So the data parses fine but now I need to return the data in product or get the object data in Product into a separate object.
Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Your $.each(this, function(key, value) is pretty useless, if you just want to shop up thfe productname

Comment: Could you not change the format of the response at the server? It seems a little odd having JSON data within JSON data.

Comment: from which server side application you're getting `json` i means you would be getting json from controller action or from service(API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I had to fix the invalid JSON by escaping the trailing quote on each

```
\"Test Product 1" <<<<
\"Test Product 2" <<<<
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        "product": "[{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332401\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 1\",\"productCode\":\"332401\"},{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332388\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 2\",\"productCode\":\"332388\"}]",
        "category": "gross_MAX_1",
        "totalCategory": 1
    },
    {
        "product": "[{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332401\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 1\",\"productCode\":\"332401\"},{\"imgUrl\":\"/p/332388\",\"prodCartQty\":2,\"prodName\":\"Test Product 2\",\"productCode\":\"332388\"}]",
        "category": "gross_MAX_1",
        "totalCategory": 1
    }
]



$.each(data,function(_,productArr) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(productArr.product.replace(/\//g,""));
  $.each(arr,function(_,productDetails) {
    // here is a product detail object
    $.each(productDetails,function(name,value) {
      console.log(name,value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, the json the server return has another json array inside it, I've been told this is the way the server has to return it. How can I work with what the server return? I need to get the info from the product section of the object.

Comment: Is there a way to get just the product array out of the object?

Comment: Hi, that did the trick thanks. I've now got the data in a format I can use. Top man.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it needs to be [unescaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451650/how-to-escape-and-unescape-quotes-in-javascript).

If you paste the JSON in a tool like [this JSON formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), you'll be able to see more clearly how it doesn't like the `\`s.

Comment: looking at my original variable, after I parse it I get: