# Sum of input values returns nothing or NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement to create a sample HTML document for an Online calculator and I have used below code to meet the requirement:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rechner</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <center>
        <form>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Zahl 1" name="num1" id="num1" class="num" autofocus required><br>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Zahl 2" name="num2" id="num2" class="num" required><br>
          <output placeholder="Ergebnis" class="text" id="Ergebnis"><br>
          <button class="btn" onclick="berechnen()">Rechne!</button>
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>

    <script>
        function berechnen() {
          var zahl1 = document.getElementsById("num1").value;
          var zahl2 = document.getElementsById("num2").value;
          var ergebnis = Number(zahl1) + Number(zahl2);
          document.getElementById("Ergebnis").value = ergebnis;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, whenever I try to calculate any numbers it either displays `nothing` or `NaN`

Can any one help me out, what I am doing wrong here?

Please dont get confused by the german names.

Comment: There are typos in your code: document.getElementsById("num1").value; should be document.getElementById("num1").value; without the 's'

Comment: There is a typo in "document.getElementsById".........it should be "document.getElementById"

Comment: Avoid the `Number` constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor `parseInt`/`parseFloat` are usually preferred

Comment: There's no way this code displays `NaN` or anything else – the typos would throw an error long before that.

Comment: THIS IS RIDICULOUS !! 
this type of questions shouldn't be on StackOverflow! This kind of typing mistakes in most widely used functions can not be a query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- Set the button type to be `button`. This will prevent the page from reloading when you click on it
- You should use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`

As such, you should have something similar to:

```
<form>
  ...
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="berechnen()">Rechne!</button>
</form>

<script>
    function berechnen() {
      var zahl1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
      var zahl2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
      var ergebnis = Number(zahl1) + Number(zahl2);
      document.getElementById("Ergebnis").value = ergebnis;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! do you maybe know why the button disappers when I click on it?

Comment: Yes. That's because you haven't closed the `<output>` tag. You'll need to close it before the `<br>` tag

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the non-existing method `getElementsById`. You should call  `getElementById` instead. I have place your button before the output, so it doesn't disappear after the calculation.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rechner</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <center>
        <form>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Zahl 1" name="num1" id="num1" class="num" autofocus required><br>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Zahl 2" name="num2" id="num2" class="num" required><br>
          <button class="btn" onclick="berechnen()">Rechne!</button><br>
          <output placeholder="Ergebnis" class="text" id="Ergebnis">        
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>

    <script>
        function berechnen() {
          var zahl1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
          var zahl2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
          var ergebnis = Number(zahl1) + Number(zahl2);
          document.getElementById("Ergebnis").value = ergebnis;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be `document.getElementById("num1").value;` and not `document.getElementsById("num1").value;`