# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Number' and 'Number'. Why?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a simple function that finds the smallest two integers in a given array. New to typescript but good with Javascript, I am wondering why would typescript complains about adding two numbers:

```
const array: Number[] = [
  2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 91, 2, 4, 32, 43, 3, 5, 3435,
];

const twoSmallest = (array: Number[]): Number[] => {
  if (array.length < 2) return array;

  const maxSum = array.reduce((acc: Number, curr: Number):Number => {
    return curr + acc;
  }, 0);

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //About to add my rest of the code here
  }
};

console.log('Result = ', twoSmallest(array));
```

Comment: Number should be lower case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Number` is the type for something created using the `Number` constructor, eg

```
const someNum = new Number(123);
```

which has [odd repercussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor) and should almost never be used.

For plain numbers - which one should be using 99% of the time - you want just `number` instead, eg

```
const array: number[] = [
  2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 91, 2, 4, 32, 43, 3, 5, 3435,
];
```

Replace all your `Number` with `number` and it'll work as desired.

You can also remove the explicit annotations when not necessary, and TypeScript will infer them for you - less manual annotations means less chance of accidentally typing something wrong.

Comment: I get that. Thank you very much for your explanation. Btw when you say explicit annotations, you mean while initializing the array right?

Comment: yeah, like `const thing: number = 3`, typescript can infer that so `const thing = 3`. Our linter config at work yells at me to always be explicit anyway, so there are differing styles out there.