# Is there way to create types like Array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Is there a way to create type in typescript with methods that when I call these methods, they have access to the variable's value? Equals what the array, for example, which has the method find.

Example:

```
const arrayVar: Array = [1,2,3];

array.find(el => el === 1);
```

In this case, find has access to the value of the array `arrayVar` without me having to pass it via a parameter to a function, for example, I wanted to create something in this way, for example:

```
const myVar: MyCustomType = 5;

myVar.add(2); // Nesse caso, o retorno seria 7.
```

I know it can be done with classes and functions, but then I would have to pass the value of "myVar" as a parameter (`function add (value1, value2)`, for example), I wanted a way to access it directly, just like the type Array does in its methods.

Comment: Have you looked into how `this` works in JavaScript?

Comment: "I know it can be done with classes and functions, but then I would have to pass the value of "myVar" as a parameter" - **that's not true**. Inside a method you have access to `this` which is the object (`myVar`) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To make a subclass of Number with new methods:

```
class SwagNumber extends Number {
  add(number: number) {
    // Tell the TS compiler that `this` is an unboxed Number
    return (this as unknown as number) + number;
  }
}
```

Then to use:

```
const six = new SwagNumber(6);
```

`six` will be typed to `SwagNumber` by the TS compiler.

And to show it works:

```
six.add(5)
> 11
```

Let's look at the Constructor used, part of the Class:

```
> six.constructor
[class SwagNumber extends Number]
```

This will also leave the original `Number` prototype unchanged, which will stop any potential issues (double dots are used to use a method on a number, to distinguish the dot from a decimal point!)

```
> 3..constructor
[Function: Number]
```

or:

```
> (3).constructor
[Function: Number]
```

See [Classes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

### However there's some danger here

Since SwagNumber is an object, and a regular number isn't an object by default (until you call its methods), comparisons won't work properly:

```
> six === 6
false
```

See [Why should you not use Number as a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor)

Comment: I 100% agree this is better than poluting the `Number` interface. its a shame TS doesnt define a way to make `const six: SwagNumber = 6` work.

Comment: @Jamiec It does - `const myNum = new SwagNumber(6)`

Comment: I mean without the `new` keyword as when you define a native Number. Something like c# implict cast between number and `SwagNumber`

Comment: @Jamiec I see - remember TS is no longer there at runtime (unlike C#) so JS needs a way to know `myNum` is `SwagNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding your `add` method to a prototype:

```
interface Number {
    add: (val:number) => number;
}

Number.prototype.add = function(val:number): number{ 
    
  return (this as number) + val;
}

var myVal: Number = 5
console.log(myVal.add(7))
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjayDeAUMicnACbkBcyAFAG5wA2VIWuUAlMgLwB8yNjmgBuQgF9ChDMKgA6AA5QA9mFUBPBRDkVyvZDHQgEYYMpANmrdtE40hHfMmKkXUCGHRQQdMAAtgAGcyYIdbZABqZEYmMUlCRihkTHUANSs0GySeZABWQgRzQOUmbSZlAHNaFPSmHUpaAHZOTiA)

Comment: Keep in mind there's already a type called `Number`, which is used for all numbers (except `BigInt`s) , in JS/TS - maybe use a different name?

Comment: @mikemaccana that was my first thought too, but if you want to extend a `Number` to add an `add` method it needs to be called `Number` - unless  im missing something in TS, which is entirely possible!

Comment: thansk for being polite! yes it's possible you just need to subclass. I didn't want to add an answer (to me this seems like the question asker got some bad information about `this`) but I've added one with a subclass of Number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke functions on an object at this point create a dedicated class. Why? Because you have structured zone where you can add/remove/edit and reuse in other part of code.

Sorry, i write in JS but you can change with no effort in TypeScript

**Create Class Element**

```js
class CustomArray {

    constructor() {
        this.arr = [];
    }

    add(value) {
        this.arr.push(value)
    }

    erase(){
        this.arr = [];
    }

    // so on...

    print(){
        console.log(this.arr)
    }

}

//I use Module, so i will use require.
module.exports = CustomArray;
```

The above class is simplest example. You can decorate with other functions. In theory as many as you want

**FOR USE INSIDE OTHER CONTEXT**

```js
const CustomArray = require("./CustomArray");

var arr = new CustomArray();
arr.add(2)
arr.print()
```