# Number as a JavaScript data type and a global object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

From [this documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number) I read that `Number` refers to both a data type and a global object. Surely it is not a coincidence that the data type and the global object are both written as `Number`, right? (I am new to JavaScript with some experience in C++ and a bit of Python, and it would make more sense to me that `Number` be both a type and a class.) What is going on here?

I stumbled on this issue by trying to write `1.isInteger()`, thinking that `1` is an instance of `Number`, and I should call the method `isInteger` on the instance. But then learned that I should write `Number.isInteger(1)` instead. What exactly is this `Number` object? Is it an instance of some class?

Comment: All types (= constructors) in JavaScript are objects themselves – specifically, function objects. `Object instanceof Function`, `Number instanceof Function`, `[] instanceof Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number` refers to a global constructor function that, when called, returns a number (or, in very strange cases, a Number object).

`number` is the string returned by the `typeof` operation - or, the word one uses to describe a number primitive.

It's only a capitalization difference, but it's quite an important distinction.

```js
const str = '34';
const num = Number(str);
console.log(typeof num);
```

> What exactly is this Number object? Is it an instance of some class?

`Number` itself is a class, kind of - a function that can be called, possibly with `new`, which will return a value that inherits from `Number.prototype`. (Although it's not syntactically forbidden, best to [never use `new` with `Number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor))

Unlike some languages, JavaScript types aren't really values you can work with and manipulate inside a script. You can *say*, when looking at a piece of code: "This variable points to a number" - and you can use the `typeof` operator to extract the string representation of the type from a value - but that's it. In actual JavaScript code, there isn't a `number` value or type that can be referenced in the code to do something with (other than when as part of a string in conjunction with the use of `typeof`). This is in contrast with, for example, TypeScript, where you could do `type NumObj = { theValue: number }` and `declare const theMap: Map<number, string>`, and lots of other interesting things - but JavaScript only has the `'number'` that `typeof` returns, and the Number constructor and its methods.

`Number` is a constructor function, but it also has [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) - methods directly on the constructor, not on the prototype object, such as `isInteger` - a utility function related to numbers that isn't that particular to a given number instance.

Comment: Thank you. What role does `Number` play in the call `Number.isInteger(1)`?

Comment: @lamc: Namespacing! If you’re familiar with static member functions in C++, it’s pretty much that. Some functions from the earliest versions of JavaScript were not so namespaced, e.g. the global `isFinite` and `parseInt`.

Comment: *“Unlike some languages, JavaScript types aren't really values you can work with and manipulate inside a script. You can say, when looking at a piece of code: "This variable points to a number" - and you can use the typeof operator to extract the string representation of the type from a value - but that's it. In actual JavaScript code, there isn't a number value or type that can be referenced in the code to do something with (other than when as part of a string in conjunction with the use of typeof).”* I think this is too vague/confusing to be useful. You can do lots of stuff with `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, **number** is a **[primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript)** - data that is **not an object** and has no methods or properties.

However, **Number** is an **object which wraps a primitive** (number). It is used to represent and manipulate numbers.
Its constructor contains constants and methods for working with numbers.

**Data type** refers **both to primitive values and objects**. This is why Number is also a data type. Number is a global object because it is an object that always exists in the global scope.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, primitives have methods and properties. `"foo".length`, `(5.26).toFixed(1)`, etc.

Comment: Primitives have no methods but still behave as if they do. When properties are accessed on primitives, JavaScript auto-boxes the value into a wrapper object and accesses the property on that object instead.